# meta tags in .net framework 4.0 in pages base on master and content pages

Tags: .net-4.0, meta-tags, master-pages, content-pages

where should i put meta tags in .net framework 4.0 in pages base on master and content pages?

mean in two below purposes :

## 1 - for each content page separately

## 2 - for all pages in master page

is there any property in master or content pages for setting meta tags and title ?(i could n't find them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are meta tags that should be on ALL pages, you put it in the `<head>` section of your master page, just like you would a normal HTML page. There's no property for it because it's not a server-side property, you just put it in your page.

For individual meta tags that are different for each content page, add a new `<ContentPlaceHolder>` in the `<head>` of your master page. That will let you define the actual content on each page.

Comment: thanks for answer / what     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"> STUFF </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> exactly do in master pages? is it necessary for content pages?

Comment: I think you want to start on MSDN, read the article How Master Pages Work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Comment: There's also a lot of good information (somewhat less technical) on Microsoft's asp.net site: http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials